# Do high votlage transmission lines disturb other electrical devices?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical-grid

I had the question myself it those high voltage transmission lines, disturb other electrical devices? Let's say I have an high voltage next to a mobile basestation, does it effekt the electrical components in the base station or the wireless communication of the antennas ?

Is there any way I could calculate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. Transmission lines can act like antennas, but they operate at around 50 Hz. The wavelength of a 50 Hz EM-wave is $6\times 10^6$ m. In order to effectively couple that energy, you'd have to have a receive antenna of $3\times 10^6 $ m length. That's not feasible.

Not only this, but of course the gain of the antenna scales with frequency and effective area. For low frequencies, even antennas of large effective area tend to be bad radiators.

Even if it COULD feasibly couple with basestation electronics, it just wouldn't happen. A base station's carrier frequency is more likely to interract with its own electronics than a power line's. And, because of this, basestation electronics is very well shielded from most frequencies of radiation, especially RF/HF radiation.

You can get calculations for all of this stuff in basic antenna design books i.e. Modern Antenna Design by Thomas Milligan.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I asked another question, where I guess you can give me the right answer aswell, would be nice if you could help me